# Joining two tables in ORM Django

Tags: django-models

There are three models Person, Author and Singer.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    class Meta:
       db_table = "Person"

class Author(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    rating = models.InegerField(null=True)
    class Meta:
       db_table = "Author"

class Singer(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    class Meta:
       db_table = "Singer"
```

I have to perform joining between Author and Singer in ORM

MySQL will be like 
select S.* from Singer as S join Author as A on S.person_id=P.person_id;

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution according to your database model would be

```
author_objects = Author.objects.filter(person=singer_object.person) # where singer_object

# now do something with the author_objects
```

Comment: Can't it be possible in single ORM statement, means instead of taking singer_object in prior.